# Missing Database Inspector selection in Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, database-inspector

I have a Pixel XL 12 emulator on Android Studio Chipmunk running with Device Manager reported Android 12.0 and API 31.  But I could not find the Database Inspector selection in View\Tool Windows at all.  It does have an App Inspection.  But there was still no tap for Database Inspector after App Inspection selected.

The app that I was running on the emulator was from Unit 5: Data persistence of Android Basics in Kotlin from Google.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to App Inspection and select process (keep app open)
and you will see Database Inspector

Comment: Great! couldn't found it before.